# Symmetric ds issue

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql8.3 and include symmetris ds 1.5.1 in my application.But the replication is done fine for client to server . but the replication is not done from server to client.
I am newer to use the symmetric ds .Can anyone plese let me know the checklist of using symmetric ds for cheching that my symmetric ds is well configure or not.

Thank You very Much

Answer (score 1):

Your description is very general, and it's not too easy to come up with any suggestions based on it. It could be that you have only set up one way replication, it could be that you have set up the root to both push and pull but not manually created a row for the client in NODE_SECURITY or it could be something different.

I suggest you first verify your configuration by looking at the SymmetricDS user guide. From there, i'd have a look at the log files (SymmetricDS usually gives some sort of sensible hint, although not always) and see if those say something. Last, I'd try out the SymmetricDS forum as you most likely will find more people there who are able to answer detailed technical questions.

Good luck!